# How to get category id's which are added in main menu?

Tags: categories, menus

I called post categories in my main menu using menu section and set them as child menu items now when I click that category menu items I need to make parent menu item active.I know doing this with jQuery for pages in this way

```
<?php if(is_page( 842 ) || is_page( 846 ) || is_page( 844 ) || is_page( 848 ) || is_page( 'current-tenders' )){?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery( window ).click(function() {

         jQuery('li.menu-item-28').addClass('tendersactive');
         alert('hi');
     });
</script>
<?php }?>
```

in `is_page( ID )` here ID is page id but how to do in this same way for categories or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `is_category()`  not worked for me but

```
if(in_category( 'articles' ))

`in_category()` worked
```

[Codex reference for in_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category).

Comment: You could have saved yourself time by just commenting to my comment straight away for extra help :-)

Comment: Thanks but really I didn't waste my time I posted this answer today coz someone with the same issue may find this useful.

Comment: :-) no problem. For that you get my upvote. Sorry for the crappy comment, wasn't intended to be that way though. Enjoy :-)